# Is the communication between activities passing JSON strings in the Extras Bundle correct?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity, bundle

I'm trying to pass some objects between activities using the intent extras bundle, I found that storing this objects in the getApplication() can be dangerous, because data can be lost when the cellphone kills your app process.

My problem is I can't make this classes Serializable or Parcelable (because they save references to other classes), so I tried to convert the objects to JSON using Gson and put them in the bundle.

```
Intent = new Intent(Constants.MY_ACTIVITY);
intent.putExtra(MyActivity.PARAM_DIRECCION, new Gson().toJson(direccion));
startActivity(intent);
```

and then retrieve this object from my other Activity:

```
if(getIntent().getExtras() != null && getIntent().getExtras().get(PARAM_DIRECCION) != null) {
    direccion = new Gson()
            .fromJson((String) getIntent().getExtras()
                    .get(PARAM_DIRECCION), Direccion.class);
```

So far so good, things work, but then playing a little bit with my app I found out there was a SIGABRT code 11, so my questions are:

Is this correct? Is there any consequence from handling data this way?
Is there any better way?

Here is the log I'm seeing :

```
09-14 12:41:37.000 372-372/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    Build fingerprint: 'motorola/titan_retla/titan_umts:6.0/MPB24.65-34-3/3:user/release-keys'
    Revision: 'p400'
    ABI: 'arm'
09-14 12:41:37.001 372-372/? A/DEBUG: pid: 13895, tid: 13912, name: FinalizerDaemon  >>> ar.com.holon.tmob <<<
    signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xdeadbaad
09-14 12:41:36.996 372-372/? W/debuggerd: type=1400 audit(0.0:1318): avc: denied { search } for uid=0 name="com.google.android.gms" dev="mmcblk0p38" ino=285 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-14 12:41:37.006 372-372/? W/debuggerd: type=1400 audit(0.0:1319): avc: denied { search } for uid=0 name="com.google.android.gms" dev="mmcblk0p38" ino=285 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
    type=1400 audit(0.0:1320): avc: denied { search } for uid=0 name="com.google.android.gms" dev="mmcblk0p38" ino=285 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
09-14 12:41:37.066 372-372/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: 'invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xb7acf598 passed to dlfree'
        r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 00000000  r3 00000002
        r4 b7acf598  r5 deadbaad  r6 b6d5bec8  r7 99386000
        r8 b7acf5a0  r9 b781ea30  sl 13704040  fp 13916d80
        ip b6d565dc  sp b4233538  lr b6d277d7  pc b6d277d6  cpsr 60070030
09-14 12:41:37.071 372-372/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
        #00 pc 000307d6  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+1285)
        #01 pc 00054559  /system/lib/libhwui.so (_ZN7android10uirenderer16RenderProperties14ComputedFieldsD1Ev+16)
        #02 pc 00054591  /system/lib/libhwui.so (_ZN7android10uirenderer16RenderPropertiesD1Ev+36)
        #03 pc 000542f5  /system/lib/libhwui.so (_ZN7android10uirenderer10RenderNodeD2Ev+112)
        #04 pc 0005432b  /system/lib/libhwui.so (_ZN7android10uirenderer10RenderNodeD0Ev+6)
        #05 pc 726f8ae5  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat (offset 0x1fd2000)
```

Comment: There's a limit on the size of the bundle, but that should work.  Or you could use the Bundle directly, adding fields from the object.  You might want to post your stack trace and code.

Comment: @GabeSechan I updated the question, I found out that comes from native code.

Comment: It does.  If you post more of it I may be able to tell you where in native it occurred.  All I can tell form that is a segfault-  accessing memory that either hasn't been allocated or was already released.

Comment: @GabeSechan I tried to reproduce the error several times but all I'm getting is the stack-trace I uploaded and this warning 

`09-14 12:41:39.520 1755-1851/? W/WindowAnimator: Failed to dispatch window animation state change.`

Comment: I just edited and added all I have got. I'm using logcat to see the exceptions, should I use another tool ?

Comment: Sorry, my screen didn't refresh, missed the change from image to text.

Comment: Its crashing in the rendering code.  I don't really think its too likely to be related to what you're doing, unless you tried to serialize a class like Paint, Canvas, or something the renderer would use directly.

Comment: If the application crashes you should have a stack trace of the classes and methods called until the crash is produced. Logcat should be showing that. See if yo are not filterning any output that could be hiding that.

Comment: @Juan i'm using the Verbose filter and nothing else, but there are no stacktraces from Java, only from the native code. I think the error was converting Location (android.location) to json, I found out It implemented parcelable, so I passed it straight through the intent and It worked fine.